# Generar consultas SQL con distintos datos automáticamente

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una base de datos con una tabla usuarios de la cual quiero ejecutar varias consultas select con distintos mails (200 aprox),estos mails los tengo guardados en un documento .txt. Un ejemplo va a ser mucho mas claro:

```
SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE email = 'ejemplo1@h.com'
SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE email = 'ejemplo2@h.com'
SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE email = 'ejemplo3@h.com'
```

Existe alguna herramienta que genere la consulta automáticamente copiando y pegando los mails? ya que hacerlo uno por uno es una tarea engorrosa y tardada.

EDIT: Lo que necesito es una herramienta en la cual yo pueda poner lo siguiente: "SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE email = ''" y pegarle los 200 mails y me genere un txt (o cualquier formato) con las consultas armadas para pegarlo en SQL

Comment: ¿Quieres que aparezcan como múltiples resultados o como un solo resultado?

Comment: Si solo quieres un resultado con la consulta puedes hacer un procedimiento que reciba los emails separados por coma,y hacer un recorrido haciendo union en cada consulta

Comment: ¿De dónde saldría el filtro que estás haciendo, es decir el valor `'ejemplo1@h.com'``?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho los mails estan en un txt aparte

Comment: @LuisCazares Es indiferente, puede ser de cualquier manera, lo que necesito es no tener que hacer un copy paste de 200 registros y agregar los 200 mails a mano

Comment: Yo lo que hago en estos casos 1) leo el TXT en un Excel 2) Armo una formula que concatene cada dato de interés con la query a ejecutar 3) Copio el resultado a ejecutar

Comment: No esta muy clara la pregunta, necesita mejorarla.